# Why the map $ w=-1/2(z+1/z)$ maps upper half disk to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have read some posts about this map( [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828711/proving-frac12z-frac1z-maps-upper-half-disk-onto-upper-half-plane) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681205/inverse-of-the-joukowski-map-phiz-z-frac1z) ). But I still do understand about it.

If I express as coordinate, if $z=re^{i\theta}=x+iy$, then $$f=w=u+iv=\dfrac{-1}{2}(z+\dfrac{1}{z})=\dfrac{-1}{2}(\cos\theta(r+\dfrac{1}{r})+i\sin\theta(r-\dfrac{1}{r}) )$$
$$f=\dfrac{-1}{2}(\dfrac{x(x^2+y^2+1)}{x^2+y^2})+i\dfrac{y(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2})$$
I can see that $f$ maps the upper half disk to subset of upper half plane, but I can not find a representation of $x$ and $y$ in term of $u$ and $v$ to show that the map is one to one and onto from upper half disk to upper half plane.

That is , how to show that for any $u\in \mathbb{R}$ and $v\in \mathbb{R}^+$, there are $x$ and $y$ from the upper half circle.

On the other hand, if I write $z^2+2wz+1=0$, I can solve that $z=-w\pm\sqrt{w^2-1}$ with $\sqrt{w^2-1}=|w^2-1|^{1/2}e^{i Arg(w^2-1)}$. Denote them by $z^+$ and 
$z^-$. Suppose I know that $z^+$ is the desired result root.

But how can I show that it is a bijective map from upper half plane to upper half disk? It seems that it is hard to compute the argument of $z=-w\pm\sqrt{w^2-1}$ and its norm for $w\in \mathbb{H}$.

In the post [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681205/inverse-of-the-joukowski-map-phiz-z-frac1z), it was stated that if we know $z^+(i)=-i+\sqrt{2}i\in\mathbb{H}$ then it is enough to say $z^+$ is the required map, but why?

And in general, why $z^+$ is the required map? It was stated that in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828711/proving-frac12z-frac1z-maps-upper-half-disk-onto-upper-half-plane) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681205/inverse-of-the-joukowski-map-phiz-z-frac1z) that $z^+z^-=1$, so if one of them is outside the circle, then another one must be inside the circle, but I think it can be that sometimes $z^+ $ may be inside the circle and sometimes $z^+ $ may be outside the circle, why there must be a fixed one?

And finally why the branch is taken $(-1,1)$ since I think the negative real axis is enough. Sorry for so many questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an alternative approach, which avoids the hassle with 
(holomorphic branches of) square roots: We have
$$
f(z) = -\frac 12 (z + \frac 1z) = \frac{\left( \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2 + 1}{\left( \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2 - 1} = T_2(S(T_1(z))
$$
where:

- $T_1(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a Möbiustransformation mapping the
  upper half-disk onto the second quadrant,
- $S(z) = z^2$ maps the second quadrant bijectively onto the lower
  half-plane, and
- $T_2(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is a Möbiustransformation mapping the
  lower half-plane onto the upper half-plane,

so that the composition is a one-to-one mapping from the upper half-disk 
to the upper half-plane.

Comment: Completely transparent.

Comment: Thanks! May I know that why $T_1$ is the map from upper half-disk onto the second quadrant? If I express it as coordinate $T_1=\dfrac{r^2-1+2ir\sin\theta}{r^2+1+2r\cos\theta}=u+iv$. I can not find $r$ in term of $u$ and $v$. Or there is a simple method?

Comment: @mnmn1993: Use that [Möbiustranformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation) map lines and circles onto lines and circles, and (as conformal maps of the extended plane) preserve angles and orientation. For example, $T_1(1)=0$, $T_1(0)=-1$, $T_1(-1)=\infty$ implies that the segment $[-1, 1]$ is mapped onto the negative real axis. Then show that the upper half of the unit circle is mapped to the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: Sorry I still dont know why it is onto by your augment, it seems that you use the fact that the connected component is mapped to the connected component by  Möbius map?

Comment: @mnmn1993: That is correct. For example, since $T_1$ maps the (extended) real axis onto itself, it maps the upper half-plane to the either the upper or the lower half-plane. Since $T_1(i) = i$ it must be the upper half-plane. One can also use an orientation argument: The upper half-plane lies to the right when moving from $1$ to $0$ on the real axis, therefore image lies to the right when moving from $T_1(1) = 0$ to $T_1(0) = -1$.

Comment: Is this true for conformal map?

Comment: @mnmn1993: A conformal map is orientation-preserving.

Comment: Where can I find a proof about the orientation principle? I can not find one in conway's book. Thanks

Comment: @mnmn1993: this might  help as a starting point https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687487/conformal-map-iff-holomorphic. The essential idea is that when viewing $f$ as a mapping of $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^2$, the Jacobian matrix is a (scaled) *rotation,* because of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: How do you prove the second one? If i want to show $f(z)=z^{2}$ is a conformal map from the second quadrant to lower half plane, the first direction is easy. But for the inverse map, I will need to use $g(w)=w^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which let us get into the trouble of square root again.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: $f(z)=z^2$ is an injective, holomorphic function from the second quadrant *onto* the lower half-plane, therefore it has a (holomorphic) inverse which maps the lower half-plane onto the second quadrant. – For $w$ in the lower half-plane, $f^{-1}(w)$ is the (unique) square root of $w$ lying in the second quadrant.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Think in polar coordinates!

Comment: @MartinR Oh I got you.. Sorry for the bad question.